# Setup Ansible server to manage several AWS Accounts using dynamic inventory?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, boto

How do I setup Ansible server to manage multiple AWS accounts using dynamic inventory, 
so, I have 20 AWS accounts and want to manage all those from single server (VPC's in all accounts are peered with each other),

I have Installed Ansible and setup boto profile one for each account, by creating 20 profiles (i.e. 20 access and secret access keys)  stored in boto credentials: ~/.aws/credentials.

Is it the right way to manage multiple accounts 
i am using AWS_PROFILE to specify boto profile while running playbooks.

Is there any other way to do this,instead of storing keys and creating boto profiles.

Answer (score 3):

From [Example: AWS EC2 External Inventory Script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script)
If you use Boto profiles to manage multiple AWS accounts, you can pass **--profile PROFILE** name to the `ec2.py` script. An example profile might be:

```
[profile dev]
aws_access_key_id = <dev access key>
aws_secret_access_key = <dev secret key>

[profile prod]
aws_access_key_id = <prod access key>
aws_secret_access_key = <prod secret key>
```

You can then run **ec2.py --profile prod** to get the inventory for the prod account, although this option is not supported by `ansible-playbook`. You can also use the **AWS_PROFILE variable** - for example:

`AWS_PROFILE=prod ansible-playbook -i ec2.py myplaybook.yml`

Comment: Is there any other way to do this instead of storing keys on ec2 instances more secure way

Comment: You can use IAM instance profile, but you will get credentials for only one profile. I can't think of any other solution to manage multiple profiles.